# Why does API Gateway return Internal Server Error when using a custom Lambda Authorizer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, aws-sdk-js

I have a `listUsers` function which was working perfectly with cognito authorizer.

Since I've changed it to a Lambda Authorizer, it returns a `500` HTTP status code.

`serverless.yml`:

```yaml
provider:
    httpApi:
        cors: true
        authorizers:
          customAuthorizer:
            type: request
            functionName: custom-authorizer
functions:
    custom-authorizer:
        handler: authorizer.handler

listUsers:
  handler: src/users/index.listUsersHandler
  events:
    - httpApi:
        path: /users
        method: get
        authorizer: customAuthorizer
```

`authorizer.js`:

```js
const { CognitoJwtVerifier } = require('aws-jwt-verify');
const Cognito = require('../shared/Cognito');

module.exports.handler = async (event) => {
    const authHeader = event.headers.authorization;
    if (!authHeader) {
        console.log('No auth header');
        return {
            isAuthorized: false,
        };
    }
    const token = authHeader.split(' ')[1];
    console.log(token);
    const verifier = CognitoJwtVerifier.create({
        userPoolId: Cognito.UserPoolId,
        tokenUse: 'access',
        clientId: Cognito.ClientId,
    });
    let payload = null;
    try {
        payload = await verifier.verify(token);
        console.log('Token is valid. Payload:', payload);
        return {
            isAuthorized: true,
        };
    } catch {
        console.log('Token is invalid.');
        return { isAuthorized: false };
    }
};
```

When I make a GET request to `/users` it correctly redirects to my custom-authorizer & in the logs I can see that the token is valid.

However, it never runs the actual `listUsers` function and in Postman I get:

```json
{
    "message": "Internal Server Error"
}
```

Comment: What do the cloud watch logs say?  It's very difficult to guess without the logs.

Comment: I just added the logs

Comment: Can you add the logs of `index.listUsersHandler`? That appears to be what's returning the error

Comment: Apparently I't doesn't even get to the listUsers function, since there are no recent logs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by adding this:

```
authorizers:
      customAuhtorizer:
         enableSimpleResponses: true
```

Answer (score 0):

The expected [output of a Lambda authoriser](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-lambda-authorizer-output.html) is essentially a principal identifier & a policy document:

- Effect: ... `Allow`/`Deny` the API Gateway execution service
- Action: ... to invoke (`execute-api:Invoke`)
- Resource: ... the specified API method

Therefore, the current Lambda authoriser response is completely incorrect, which is why you get an internal server error:

```js
return {isAuthorized: true};
```

As a good starting point, use the `methodArn` property on the `event` object ([`event.methodArn`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-lambda-authorizer-input.html#w38aac15b9c11c26c29b5)) as the resource. This is the the ARN of the method that the caller is requesting, provided by AWS.

This method will return a minimal but correct authoriser response:

```js
function generatePolicy(principalId, effect, resource) {
    return {
        principalId,
        policyDocument: {
            Version: '2012-10-17',
            Statement: [{
                Action: 'execute-api:Invoke',
                Effect: effect,
                Resource: resource
            }]
        }
    };
}
```

Usage:

```js
const authHeader = event.headers.authorization;

if (!authHeader) {
    console.log('No auth header');
    return generatePolicy('user', 'Deny', event.methodArn);
}

...

try {
    const payload = await verifier.verify(token);
    return generatePolicy('user', 'Allow', event.methodArn);
} catch {
    return generatePolicy('user', 'Deny', event.methodArn);
}
```

Comment: I finally figured out why it wasn't working: this response is right for REST APIs, but I was using [HTTP API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-lambda-authorizer.html).